# Can a soap film be expanded infinitely?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

Consider a rectangular wire frame with a sliding wire of length *l*. When the frame is dipped in soap solution, a soap film is formed over it. Assume that there is no friction between the arms and the sliding wire and let *S* be the surface tension. Now, a force *S×2l* is applied to pull the wire outwards so as to increase the area of the film.

Now, my question is, since this force remains constant (unlike Hook's law), does this mean that the soap film can be expanded infinitely? If no, then does that mean that surface tension isn't constant (since the force would have to increase to prevent infinite pulling)? Also, when (or at what amount of force applied) will the film break?

Answer (score 4):

No, it can't. At some point the soap film gets so thin it becomes an almost-monolayer. stretching it past that point will make it tear.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing physical can be stretched infinitely because it will then be stretched infinitely thin and this is not possible since atoms have a finite size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an image of a soap film which is thinner at the top than at the bottom due to the soap solution moving downwards under the influence of gravity.
The film is viewed using white light as the water drains down and the film gets thinner and thinner at the top.

[image]

At the top the film is "black" because there is no reflected light or rather the reflected light from the two surfaces which are very close together differ in phase by $\pi$ and so interfere destructively.
In this region the film is less than a quarter of a wavelength thick and approaching the theoretical minimum of a thickness equal to the diameter of one molecule.

Lower down the path length between the two surfaces is such that constructive interference can occur.